# Is there a way to approve all future erc20 tokens for a contract?

Tags: erc-20, erc-20-approve

I wanted to write a Smart Will contract that basically sends everything in my address to a beneficiary's address if I die.

However I don't want to send everything to the smart contract in advance because I am still alive and want to buy / sell erc20 tokens I find interesting.

The problem is, I can certainly approve all tokens I hold today. However if I buy a new erc20 token tomorrow, this smart contract won't have the approval to send that new token.

So how would I approve all future erc20 tokens? I'm thinking this isn't possible, so I'm wondering what are my alternatives? Is there a way for this to happen?

Comment: If and only if you know all erc20 tokens that you are going to buy in the future.

Comment: @goodvibration that's what I figured. Is there any EIP I can take a look at that might solve my problem?

Comment: @TerenceChow no, not really. Can you know all the websites that you are going to access in the future?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not possible directly - you would have to know in advance all the tokens you will buy and their addresses (maybe they don't even exist yet). Also I can't see how any EIP would help you with that since you can't approve a token which doesn't exist.

Unfortunately I can't also think of any way you could do this with a contract since you want to hold the tokens at your own address and not in the contract's. Because you hold the tokens, it's you who has to add an allowance for them to be moved. So it would have to be some system outside the blockchain which does this on your behalf - maybe a backend system which notices your new tokens and automatically creates an allowance for your contract on your behalf?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it more passive way, like whenever you buy a new token you can give allowance to the smart contract with a higher value(mostly the tokenSupply of the token) and later the beneficiary address can call a function in the smart contract to transfer these tokens directly from your wallet to their wallet.